# How to use a WSDL with ASP.NET Web API

Tags: asp.net, ajax, web-services, wsdl

Please let me know if the premise of my question even makes sense...

I have a WSDL file from an existing (locally served) web service. I would like to "wrap" that web service with a Web API so I can easily make RESTful AJAX calls to it. If I add the WSDL as a Service Reference, I can write controllers and make calls.

I guess my questions are two things:

1. Is there some easy way to expose all the WSDL actions without manually writing controllers for each one?
2. Is this even a good idea in concept? Is there a better way to create a nice client AJAX relationship that I'm not thinking of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is a good idea in concept. Abstracting the ASMX for the clients and providing an easy REST based endpoint is good.

I'm assuming the ASMX is a separate component in itself and doesn't share any Middle-tier code with your Web API project.

It is okay to abstract out the ASMX.

As for an easy way to expose all the WSDL actions as controller actions, how many Web methods are we talking about?

Typically we only have a single ASMX web service with a few web methods. (5-15)
If you have just a few, creating a single controller with 10-15 actions should not be that painful.

On the other hand, if you have unmanageable number of web methods, you might want to think of Text Template files (.tt) to generate controllers out of 'Reference.cs' files. (proxy file) i don't think there are auto-tools to convert asmx to a web api controller.

i have found it easier to hand-write the web api controller due to the nitty-gritty of the request/response types, return types, [FromBody] [FromUri] attributes, HttpPost, HttpGet attributes, and of course the action definition itself.

The text template logic could get error-prone trying to figure out HttpPost actions vs. HttpGet etc.

Also, a good controller will end up having injected dependencies for Data Access, Caching etc. and you would want direct control on the class, rather than being created by an automatic tool.

Comment: Thanks for the quick and thorough response.